# Working with array returned from fetch function

Tags: javascript, next.js

I need a set of eyes to help me out. First of all I should say that I am not getting an error, however I just don't understand why I couldn't handle the returned data from the api call outside of the function.
So I have this function fetchUser that makes a call to the API, and returned the data successfully. But what I want is to  be able to use this data in my JSX. Below is the function call to the API route:

```
export default function Dashboard({ session }) {
  const fetchUser = async () => {
    try {
      const baseUrl = `/api/user`;
      let response = await fetch(baseUrl);
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data); //Data came back as expected as such ' [{…}] '
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
return (
   <>
   ...
   </>
)
};

console.log(fetchUser());
```

I would like to use the data here outside of the function, but getting this in the console:

```
Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Array(1)
```

Basically I would like to just get the array back and work with it, but getting the whole "promise" thing - Please help point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: `fetchUser()` is an async function, you need to `await` or use `.then()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait for the `Promise` to complete with `.then`.

```js
fetchUser().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```